# What was the first chess-playing automaton?

Tags: history, engines

One well-known automaton is [The Turk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk). What is the first one and when was it constructed, including fake ones?  [1]:

Comment: Just to be clear: for the purpose of your question, do you count The Turk as a "chess-playing automaton," or do you discount it since it was really a person doing the playing?

Comment: I remember reading that computers were able to win K + R vs K endings as early as 1920s. I tried to google for verification of that, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first chess machine:

"In 1769 the Hungarian engineer Baron Wolfgang von Kempelen built a chess playing machine for the amusement of the Austrian Queen Maria Theresia. It was a purely mechanical device, shaped like a Turk. Naturally its outstanding playing strength was supplied by a chess master cleverly hidden inside the device. The machine was a fake."!

[image: 1769 fake chess machine]

From: [A short history of computer chess, by Frederic Friedel](http://www.chessbase.com/columns/column.asp?pid=102)

So "the Turk" that you mentioned was the first one.

Answer (score 14):

In 1910 [Leonardo Torres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_Torres_y_Quevedo#Chess_Automaton) developed a machine he called "[El Ajedrecista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Ajedrecista)". It was capable of automatically playing K+R vs K endgames without human intervention. It was publicly demonstrated for the first time in 1914.

Comment: Very cool. I'd never heard of this before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was a little unclear earlier. I'm looking for even fake automatons. But this answer is still useful. +1